# Bot embed, put 2 fields per line on all lines

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I would like my bot sends an embed containing 8 fields arranged on 4 lines (2 per line), I already succeeded by putting inline=True/False but now it does not work anymore, I manage to modify the provisions but impossible to put 2 per line from beginning to end

(sorry for bad english I use google traduction)

Comment: Please provide us with snippet of your code that you have managed to do already, so we can help you

Comment: I can not because I changed this code to make it work again (which I did not manage to do) :/

Comment: I was looking for the same solution and this answer helped. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66485287/how-to-make-a-discord-embed-with-only-2-columns