# How to make a Discord embed with only 2 columns

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I am trying to make an embed with only 2 columns. Whenever I delete the inline value it drops test3 field like I want. Then I keep inline: true on test4 field and it drops to another row. I tried making both test3 and test4 inline values false but the problem still exists. How can I correct this?

**Update:**
After playing with it some more I found that when I make a 5th field it splits the column again. Is there anyway I can hide test3 but keep the field?

**My embed looks like this**

[image]

**My Code:**

````
command(client, 'test' , (message) => {

      const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
     
         .setTitle('Test')
         .setColor('#C69B6D')
         .addFields(  
           {
              name: 'test1' ,
              value: "```TESTING```",
              inline: true,
            },
            {
               name: 'test2' ,
               value: "```TESTING```",
               inline: true,
             },
             {
               name: 'test3' ,
               value: "```TESTING```",
               
             },
             {
               name: 'test4' ,
               value: "```TESTING```",
               inline: true,
             },

         )
      


      message.channel.send(embed).then(msg => {})
 
   })
````

**Updated Embed:**

[image]

**My Updated Code:**

````
   command(client, 'test' , (message) => {

      const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
     
         .setTitle('Test')
         .setColor('#C69B6D')
         .addFields(  
           {
              name: 'test1' ,
              value: "```TESTING```",
              inline: true,
            },
            {
               name: 'test2' ,
               value: "```TESTING```",
               inline: true,
             },
             {
               
               
             },
             {
               name: 'test4' ,
               value: "```TESTING```",
               inline: true,
             },
             {
               name: 'test5' ,
               value: "```TESTING```",
               inline: true,
             },

         )
      


      message.channel.send(embed).then(msg => {})
 
   })
````

Comment: Have you tried a generator for your needs? Many available to do the boring work for you.
Embeds work tricky too, if you create one and try to modify it with different columns/etc it will likely fail. You may need to implement a trick like HelpBoxEmbed, UserEmbed, SearchEmbed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `.addField('\u200b', '\u200b')` to add an empty field

See the [discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#using-the-richembedmessageembed-constructor) for more information

Comment: I came in here looking for a way to add many fields to an embed message from a for-loop but to be displayed in two columns but it seems there isn't any. Your answer is though a good way to add one or two extra empty fields in case the list is not multiple of three (list.length % 3 !==0).

Answer (score 1):

Use '\t' escaped symbol instead of '\u200b' or '\b':

````js
.addFields(  
           {
              name: 'test1' ,
              value: "```TESTING```",
              inline: true,
            },
            {
               name: 'test2' ,
               value: "```TESTING```",
               inline: true,
             },
             {
               name: "\t",
               value: "\t"
             },
             {
               name: 'test4' ,
               value: "```TESTING```",
               inline: true,
             },
             {
               name: 'test5' ,
               value: "```TESTING```",
               inline: true,
             },

         )
````

[Discord  embed example](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1120074719727726704/1207188589893656596/b84160ad8253aa46.png?ex=65debcfc&is=65cc47fc&hm=50650e52d30a59371b082c23c936ea3c42bd5b7d23ab00c7dd1c6ecec43768de&=&format=webp&quality=lossless)